# Nested API resources with angularjs

Tags: django, rest, angularjs, tastypie

I am using tastypie which uses nested resources. Which means when i make a call to my photos resource the response is as such

```
{
name: "photo name",
description: "some description",
tags: [
"/api/v1/tags/1/", "/api/v1/tags/2/"
]
```

What is the best way of dealing with this in angularjs? currently I am resorting to make $http calls for each of the returned nested resources when displaying the data. Is there any way I can use ng-resource to automatically make api calls for nested resources?

Comment: I've only used tastypie not angular so I can't help with a solution only in javascript. I removed my answer so others wouldn't ignore the the question...

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Comment: I have used http://django-rest-framework.org/ with angular with no issues. I am always able to use the returned data as a javascript object like `object.tags[1]` would give "/api/v1/tags/2/"

Comment: Have you tried using full=true in the resources itself?